# Ошибки при создании сайта на Django на этапе создания migrations для models

Tags: django

Вот что выводит в консоль:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\python3\Django\myfirst>python manage.py makemigrations ar
ticles
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\
django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\
django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\
django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\
django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\
django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__in
it__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\python3\Django\myfirst\myfirst\apps\articles\mode
ls.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Article(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\python3\Django\myfirst\myfirst\apps\articles\mode
ls.py", line 4, in Article
    article_title = models.CharField("name of string", max_Length = 200)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\
django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1037, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_Length'
```

P. S. : Прикрепил файлы сайта в архиве https://www.mediafire.com/file/3w5kny4ft6kyiz8/myfirst.rar/file

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

У `CharField` нет атрибута `max_Length`. Вероятно, вы имели ввиду `max_length`.